# How to avoid "variable was written to, but never read" warning with a timer in Swift

Tags: swift, timer, warnings, var

I'm using this code to delay the appearance/disappearance of a tableView.

```
    var timer = NSTimer()
    let delay = 0.5
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delay, target: self, selector: #selector(delayedHideTableView), userInfo: nil, repeats: false) // Warning: Variable 'timer' was written to, but never read
```

Maybe there is something I do wrong with the timer variable, how can avoid this error? I know that I can use a print(timer) statement but I don't think this can be considered a best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create the `timer` variable since it is not required. Just do below:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(delayedHideTableView), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Even you don't need the `delay` variable unless it changes dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

Always remember to invalidate timer when the class is deinit or view is removed, otherwise it would cause hard-to-find memory crash in the future.

so just add:

```
deinit {
  self.timer.invalidate()
}
```

in your class.

I've seen lots of weird bugs due to not deinit timer, observors, etc. So keep a good habit.

Comment: Actually an `NSTimer` will keep its target retained (and the run-loop retains the timer), therefore `deinit` will never be called so long as the timer is active. You will need to call `invalidate()` manually at the appropriate time in the object's lifecycle. Although in this case OP's timer doesn't repeat – so the target will only be retained until it's fired.

Comment: Interesting, I worked a lot on repeated timers, but few on non-repeated timers. So I'm not sure if it's important in this situation. Just curious, if the timer is initialized, then the tableView is removed from superview somehow, then the timer is fired, would that cause any problem? when the tableView is still in memory or not.

Comment: The timer will keep the target retained as long as it's active, so even if you have no references to the given target – the timer does. This is exactly, as you say, to prevent issues that could be caused by attempting to call a method on a deallocat(ed/ing) object. If you're looking for a way to avoid this behaviour, then take a look at `CFRunLoopTimer` – which can take a closure as a callback instead of a target and selector.

Comment: @originaluser2 Good to hear that, I image those high-level language should automatically handle those stuff. But I did have crashes before when I didn't deinit the repeated timer, and it cost me lots of time to debug. So I don't quite understand "The timer will keep the target retained as long as it's active" you said. Did I miss something?

Comment: Without looking at your code, I couldn't say what the problem was – but I assure you that `NSTimer` retains its target :) Take a look at the description of `target` parameter on [`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(_:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)

Comment: @originaluser2 I think you are right, the timer keeps its target function. But those crashes may happen when the target function is dealing with the class itself and the class itself already deinit? just a guess.

Comment: But the instance can never enter the `deinit` until there are no strong references left to it (as managed by ARC). And the timer will keep a strong reference to it as long as it's running – once the timer is invalidated, the target selector cannot be called by it. So I don't see how the situation you're describing could arise, although I might be overlooking something.

Answer (score 4):

In your code there are a few issues:

1. You are declaring `timer` as a variable, you are populating it with `NSTimer()` and 2 lines below you are overwriting that value. So why do you assign `NSTimer` to `timer` in first place?
2. If you don't use the value returned by `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(...)` why are you saving it into `timer`?
3. Finally to call a method using selector into a class that does not inherit `NSObject` you should expose that method with `@objc`.
4. The correct syntax for `#selector` is `#selector(ClassName.methodName)`

So

```
class Foo {

    func foo() {
        let delay = 0.5
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delay, target: self, selector: #selector(Foo.delayedHideTableView), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    @objc func delayedHideTableView() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example you con't really need a variable for a NSTimer at all. so you can delete

```
var timer = NSTimer()
```

as user Code pointed out it is already initiating a timer there. So if you need this variable you should rather do

```
var timer:NSTimer
```

This will not initiate a timer but set the type of the property as a correct one.

But a short answer to your problem is that you can just make the code look like this:

```
let delay = 0.5
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delay, target: self, selector: #selector(delayedHideTableView), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

and the warning will be gone.